# NetLogo can 3d model be saved as Netlogo web?

Tags: netlogo

Just wondering if NetLogo 3d model is allowed to export as NetLogo Web? Because I notice that the button for export to NetLogo Web in 3d version is grayed out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot. NetLogo Web is 2D-only.